# Criar select para retornar última vez que algo foi diferente de zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft-azure, tsql

Tenho uma tabela chamada `Estoque`, onde tem as colunas `NOME_PRODUTO`, `DATA`, ,entre outras.
A ideia é que quando eu fizer um `SELECT` Usando a data como parâmetro me sejam retornados todos os produtos que tinham no estoque naquele dia, Ex:

```
SELECT NOME_PRODUTO 
FROM ESTOQUE 
WHERE DATA = '20170220'
```

É ai onde as coisas começam a dificultar, gostaria que se não tivesse um determinado produto no estoque, fosse apresentado a ultima vez que esse produto esteve no estoque, exemplo:

```
SELECT NOME_PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE, DATA
FROM ESTOQUE
WHERE DATA = '20170220'
```

Usando como exemplo, o PRODUTO_D esteve no estoque pela última vez em 15/02/2017, o retorno seria:

```
    NOME_PRODUTO   QUANTIDADE      DATA 
     PRODUTO_A         10        20170220
     PRODUTO_B         7         20170220
     PRODUTO_C         9         20170220
     PRODUTO_D         3         20170215
```

Lembrando que no estoque pode conter centenas de produtos e toda vez que um produto é atualizado no estoque, é criado um novo registro com o nome, quantidade, data e outras informações, mantendo também o registro antigo.
E nem sempre vou fazer a busca pela data atual.

Como resolvo esse problema, tentei usando a cláusula `CASE`, mas eu não soube fazer.

Obrigado

Comment: Você tem alguma tabela com informações de produtos ou apenas esta, estoque ?

Comment: O que deve acontecer quando você consulta a data 20170215? Devem ser exibidos os registros do dia 20170220 (PRODUTO_A = 10; PRODUTO_B = 7 e PRODUTO_C = 9)? Ou devem ser considerados somente os registros anteriores a data 20170215?

Comment: @CA_93: Como está declarada a coluna DATA?

Answer (score 1):

"CA_93", há algumas abordagens para atender ao que necessita. A mais tradicional é o uso da função [row_number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734.aspx) para numerar as linhas de estoque de cada produto pela data, mas em ordem inversa, onde o mais recente sempre recebe o número 1.

```
-- código #1
declare @DataEstoque date;
set @DataEstoque= Convert(date, '20/2/2017', 103);

--
with Estoque_Recente as (
SELECT NOME_PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE, DATA, 
       Seq= row_number() over (partition by NOME_PRODUTO order by DATA desc)
  from ESTOQUE
  where DATA <= @DataEstoque
        and QUANTIDADE > 0
)
SELECT NOME_PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE, DATA
  from Estoque_Recente
  where Seq = 1;
```

- A variável @DataEstoque deve ser declarada da mesma forma que a coluna DATA.